# the saved image cannot be opened

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

My program generates some numpy array during the running process, I save them using

```
   from skimage import io
   io.imsave("img.tif",imgs[0,0])
```

The `imgs` is of type `float32`, shape `(1,1,128,128)`; while the maximum value is `1.0` and minimum value is `0.0`. The image is correctly saved. However, when I open it, I got the following error message. What can the reason?

[image]

Comment: try converting to 8 bit uint? `io.imsave("img.tif",(imgs[0,0]*255).astype(np.uint8))`

Answer (score 0):

After testing what I suggested in the comments, I'm quite sure that's your exact problem. (I reproduced the exact error)

Tiff images don't support just any arbitrary color-space. commonly supported types include 8 bit grey-scale, 16 bit grey-scale, bi-level (binary), color palette, rgb (24 bit typical).

convert to 8 bit grey-scale (probably most commonly supported after rgb) with this edit:

```
io.imsave("img.tif",(imgs[0,0]*255).astype(np.uint8))
```